# Is it possible to generate small executables with MINGW g++?

Tags: linker, g++, compilation

I understand that MINGW-g++ compiles larger executables because it statically links many things. On the other hand MSVC++ links dynamically against DLLs from the VCRedist package, and that is why it produces way smaller executables.

However, is it possible to compile with g++ in a similar manner on windows? Not necessarily MINGW-g++ but something that I can use with Qt Creator (I didn't add Qt as a tag because it's irrelevant to the question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MinGW is perfectly capable of linking to the msvcrt runtime dynamically. The only mess you're not getting rid of this way is GCC/MinGW startup code, which is not very large.

A small C++ test program (simple iostream hello world program, note: I got the same results for a plain C printf version).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Commandlines:

```
g++ main.cpp -MD -Os -s -o test.exe
cl /MD /Os main.cpp /link /out:test2.exe
```

Executable file sizes:

GCC: 13kB

MSVC: 6kB

***Although this is double, all necessary startup code accounts for the large difference; for larger programs, the difference is negligible.***

Comment: Is the -MD switch that makes it link against the VC runtime?

Comment: MinGW always links against the VC runtime (the msvcrt.dll in C:\Windows\System32). `-MD` just does exactly the same thing as `/MD` for MSVC. I think you misunderstand what MinGW is/does: it builds native executables just like Visual Studio compilers, but with the GNU toolchain. Therefore, there is a small bit of code not shared between the two, but all that is always hidden away from the user. Also the C++ ABI differs a bit (and g++ links to GCC's libstdc++, instead of MS's, in contrast to the C library, which is the same in both cases), but that about sums up the difference.

Comment: Did you try stripping binaries?

Comment: Yes, I did that. Also, UPX (which strips, too). My problem was specifically with Qt applications that I saw some of the pre-compiled examples were about ~100K in size but when I recompiled them they were 5-8 times larger and not with a debug build. Thankfully I just learned that using the MS compiler with Qt is just a matter of using the MSVC version Qt SDK.

Comment: @Tamas: what is very possible in your case is that you're using a MinGW version with only a static build of the C++ standard library, which could explain the extra bloat. Mine uses libstdc++ as a dll. But indeed, using MSVC with Qt is not hard at all.

Answer (score 3):

To make a fair comparison between VC++ and MinGW using static linking, I would suggest removing the compiler switch /MD in the command line syntax above. This will cause the Visual C++ compiler to link statically with static libraries instead but still, the Visual C++ compiler will generate a much smaller executable than the one compiled statically with MinGW.

Because the linker used by the Visual C++ compiler has a feature called function-level linking, with this, the linker only links the necessary libraries based on the functions used in your code. Any unreferenced or unused functions will not be linked to the final executable generated resulting in a much smaller statically linked binary.

Going back to the example above using the Visual C++ compiler and this time, using the static linking, the command line syntax would be:

cl /Os main.cpp /link /out:test2.exe

You can notice here that I have removed the /MD switch so that the compiler will use static linking instead of dynamic.

Now, to make a much smaller statically linked executable, I suggest the command line syntax:

cl /Ox main.cpp /link /FILEALIGN:512 /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /INCREMENTAL:NO /out:test2.exe

If you check the resulting binary, you will notice that it is much smaller which is again, a statically linked executable.

I actually got this idea from the discussion on this website at http://www.catch22.net/tuts/minexe

Most Pascal compilers including Delphi also have the same linking feature and it is known as smart linking but the resulting statically linked executables are much smaller the those produced by the Visual C++ compiler.

The linker used by MinGW is very dumb, it is bloat unaware and therefore, it links many static libraries including those which contains functions or routines which are not used in your source code at all leading to a very bloated statically linked binaries.

I would advise dumping MinGW and use the Visual C++ compiler instead. Even the developer of MinGW doesn't seem to care on reducing code bloat using static linking.

Comment: Is there a drop-in replacement for the linker in MinGW? I'd like to stay with g++ because most applications I develop are meant to be cross-compiled to Linux and Windows. If I use g++ on both platforms it is relatively painless.

Comment: For the drop-in replacement, I'm trying to search on google at this time and right now, I haven't found any suitable answer yet. Since you really want to stay with g++ without any code bloat, I advise you use dynamic linking for this compiler and include the necessary DLLs or libraries in your application if you wish to deploy it to other machines in order to avoid dependency problems also known as DLL hell in Windows environment.

Comment: If you will develop your application in Linux, the gcc and g++ compiler that comes with it uses dynamic linking by default and as far as I know, most Linux distributions have all the necessary runtime libraries for the applications you develop, so, there might be no need to worry about the necessary runtime libraries to be included in your application if you want to deploy it on other machines using Linux.

Comment: Yes, the default setup in Qt Creator also links Qt itself dynamically to the application. The advised deployment method is to ship the dlls in the application directory. This works and OK. What I'm not completely OK with is that the main exe size is bigger with gcc as compared to VC++ (even though both link to Qt dynamically).

Comment: How big is the difference in size between the one compiled with VC++ compared to the one with MinGW using dynamic build? If it is small, then there is no need to bother yourself on this.

Comment: As far as I know, the MinGW compiler adds the necessary startup code to your application which also results in a bigger executable even in dynamic build. Actually, other compilers also do this including the Microsoft compilers. Most probably, the startup code added by the MinGW compiler might be different from the one used by the Microsoft compilers which is why the MinGW executables are still larger than Microsoft even in dynamic build.

Comment: Have you tried to use the strip utility that comes with MinGW? This would potentially reduce your executable size.

Comment: If you are still eager to make your application smaller even in dynamic build without any debugging informations in it, then you may want to read the online documentation for MinGW. On that page, you will find all the compiler and linker switches which you may use in combination with each other which might even help reduce your application size even a bit. But, you may spend some time in doing experiments on this just to get the right compiler and linker switch combinations.

Comment: Of course I'm not comparing a debug build to a release build of VC++. The difference is 100 kB vs 500 kB which of course get's smaller with bigger executables, but still pretty significant. I'll try to use the intel compiler and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cygwin (www.cygwin.com). They use a runtime DLL much like MSVCRT . Then your program depends on the cygwin runtime, of course (kind of a tautology, sorry).